# Get wrong result using toLocaleString module in javascript

Tags: javascript

I get wrong result when using toLocaleString method in javascript

Current month output = M01, Expected month output = January

has anyone experienced same issue and solved ?

```js
const milisecond = 1614237860725;
const expiryDate = new Date();
expiryDate.setTime(milisecond);
const month = expiryDate.toLocaleString('default', {
  month: 'long'
});
console.log(month)
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please change my millisecond to yours. I get Februrary with the milliseconds I used

Comment: Are you using node.js with small ICU? The small ICU doesn't include the locale data

Answer (score 0):

I'm only assumming here (because you don't mention node.js at all), but you get `M01` for January when node.js was compiled with the "small ICU", which doesn't include the locale data (other than English).

It's in the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html#intl_embed_a_limited_set_of_icu_data_small_icu

Quoting from the docs (look at the comments in the sample):

> This option makes the resulting binary link against the ICU library statically, and includes a subset of ICU data (typically only the English locale) within the node executable.
>
> Functionalities that only require the ICU library itself, such as String.prototype.normalize() and the WHATWG URL parser, are fully supported under small-icu. Features that require ICU locale data in addition, such as Intl.DateTimeFormat, generally only work with the English locale:

```js
const january = new Date(9e8);
const english = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'long' });
const spanish = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es', { month: 'long' });

console.log(english.format(january));
// Prints "January"
console.log(spanish.format(january));
// Prints "M01" on small-icu
// Should print "enero"
```